# Mysql trigger create table name based on users form data

Tags: mysql

Thanks for reading first of all. I've been searching and trying for a few days now to no avail.

I have a form users fill in which populates a mysql database. A trigger is set for after insert.

I need to use the UserID as a table name for each user. The tables all contain the same colums but need different names.

For example my basic idea of

```
  CREATE TABLE NEW.UiD
  (
  ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  );
```

Also tried setting a variable first then using that as the table name.

Unfortunately this is honestly the best way to impliment this database.

As I'm sure you're thinking already "what an idiot". Well indeed I am feeling that way.

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: **BAD** design. You do not want to have a separate table for every user. Add a `user` field to your existing table so you can assign ownership of records to individual users. ONE table, multiple records for multiple users.

Comment: What you want to accomplish with that? Maybe if you explain what you need we can point out a better design to your problem.

Comment: Sorry just trying to work out how to describe without breching a damn NDA. I need a table to contain all users sign up details. The user will then have their own table for others to add data to. By having each users table seperate to allow for multiple other users to input data.

Comment: For example one user signs up to the service and defines their own name for a table. Other users signed up to a seperate service then use the defined name as a key to post data to the other users table via php. Sorry I know its somewhat vague. I just cannot think of another way of doing it.